# How to create a folder in c?

Tags: c, windows

I tried to create a file and I did.

Now I'm trying to create the file inside a new folder, but this code doesn't work!

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main( void)
{
    FILE *fp;

    fp = fopen("txt/example.txt", "w"); // This only works without "txt/"

    fprintf(fp, "%s", "Some data here");

    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

---

Maybe I need to create the folder before and only after the file, but I don't know how to achieve it... any help is appreciated!

Comment: yes, the directory has to exist first. `mkdir()`

Comment: `CreateDirectory()` on windows.

Comment: And you have to check if it's already there too..

Comment: Incidentally, forward slashes as path separators are best avoided on Windows.  They'll work in this case, but it's a bad habit to get into.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This example makes the directory before it creates the file, and when it makes the file, note the double `\\` in the file name to prevent an escape sequence being attempted from `\e`, although it does work with a single `/` too.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <direct.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void fatal(char *msg) {
    printf("%s\n", msg);
    exit (1);
}

int main(void) {
    FILE *fp;
    if (mkdir("txt"))
        fatal ("Error creating directory");
    if ((fp = fopen("txt\\example.txt", "w")) == NULL)
        fatal ("Error opening file");
    if (fprintf(fp, "%s", "Some data here") <= 0)
        fatal ("Error writing to file");
    if (fclose(fp))
        fatal ("Error closing the file");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [`CreateDirectory`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363855%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to create a directory on windows.